# Sending Serial Data via AudioQueue in conjunction with Audio via Audio Out

Tags: ios, audio, core-audio, avaudiosession, uart

Looking to send 9600 baud symbols generated from AudioQueue syncronized with audio, both of which will output via audio out port. If the serial data is at 19.2kHz is that effectively out of hearing range? Trying to get the audio out clean without audible distortion from serial data.

Thanks for input.

Comment: 19.2 kHz might be out of the hearing range of adults, but young children and dogs can be annoyed by it.  Also, 19.2 kHz binary symbols will be distorted by a 44.1 kHz sample rate, as the total modulated bandwidth will exceed Nyquist.

Comment: Interesting. How does total modulation exceed 22.05 kHz limit? Thought 19.2 was the carrier frequency.

Comment: Don't forget to calculate the sideband bandwidth if you wish to amplitude or phase modulate your 19.2 carrier to carry any data.

Comment: Looking into it. Thanks